# R data.table changes values of other variables by reference

Tags: r, data.table

I'm using data.table in R and getting very unintuitive behaviour: changing the data.table, e.g., adding a column 'C', changes the *value* of an already set variable storing the column names from before.

I'd expect `nm` to stay as `"A" "B"`, not change to `"A" "B" "C"`.

Any explanation for this behaviour?

Thanks

```
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.12.8 using 16 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com
> d <- data.table(A=1, B=2)
> (nm <- colnames(d))
[1] "A" "B"
> d[, C := 3]
> nm
[1] "A" "B" "C"


> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_AU.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_AU.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_AU.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_AU.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.12.8
```

Comment: I don't disagree that this behavior is perhaps unexpected: my starting understanding of `data.table` is that the *data* uses referential semantics, and do not immediately assume that that would also apply to variables referencing *attributes* of a frame (e.g., column names). Recognize that attributes are stored along with an object. Knowing that `data.table` attempts to do as much as it can *in-place* (no copies) means it does so with attributes as well as data. Good question as it makes one realize the depth of `data.table`'s referential semantics.